# How to make a ring with Three.js?

Tags: 3d, three.js

I'm trying to make a 3D model of a ring (like the ones you put on a finger and just a circular ring) using Three.js.

I think I can use the tube geometry class/object:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/geometries/TubeGeometry.js

Looking at the source it seems like I need these parameters:

```
path, segments, radius, radiusSegments, closed, debug
```

And the only one that is mandatory is path.  However, I don't know how to set a path:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/core/Path.js

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/57/#Reference/Extras.Core/Path

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/57/#Reference/Extras.Core/CurvePath

Are there any tutorials, documentation, or snippet of code that can teach me how to set a path?

If there's anything else you can send me to guide me in making a 3D model of a ring, that would be greatly appreciated.  I'm not even sure if using the tube geometry class/object would work, but that's just my first try at it.

Thank you for your time and take care!

Update:
Using TorusGeometry, I've got this:
[image: Default Torus]

I'm still working on moving the object around so I can see the other "sides" of the object, but was wondering if it's possible to "flatten" the outer and inner walls of the Torus.  I'll post another question and link to it from here if I can't figure out how to view the torus and "flatten" the inner/outer walls.

Thanks again for looking!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easier than that.

```
THREE.TorusGeometry( radius, tubeRadius, radialSegments, tubularSegments )
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm playing with it but am stuck with figuring out how the "underside" looks.  So I've added a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750532/is-there-a-plugin-to-add-rotation-to-three-js-self-learning-project to help me see the changes.  I've also attached a screenshot, but was wondering is it possible to make the torus' inner and outer "wall" flat?  I couldn't tell at the moment.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You should probably make a new post and explain what you mean by "flatten".

Comment: Ooops...sorry.  I thought I accepted this answer already.  Thanks again!