# Is there a plugin to add rotation to three.js self-learning project?

Tags: three.js, trackball

I'm starting to play with three.js and was wondering if there's a simple plugin to add the trackball functionality so I can see how the changes I'm making in code is affecting the "underside" of the simple object.

I tried to follow:

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/misc_controls_trackball.html

But I'm getting a lot of EventDispatcher errors.

By try, I mean I've:

- added "TrackballControls.js"
- added "Detector.js"
- added this bit of code:

  ```
  if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
  var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
  controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
  controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
  controls.panSpeed = 0.8;
  controls.noZoom = false;
  controls.noPan = false;
  controls.staticMoving = true;
  controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;
  controls.keys = [ 65, 83, 68 ];
  controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
  ```

I did notice that the three.js used in the example is different than the one at (but not sure if it matters):

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r53/three.min.js

Any suggestions would be extremely helpful as I'm just starting out.

Thank you for your time!

Update:
I tried using the latest build of Three.js from here:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/build/three.js

I couldn't find official builds of TrackballControls.js and Detector.js so I used these versions:

http://threejsdoc.appspot.com/doc/three.js/src.source/extras/controls/TrackballControls.js.html

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/js/Detector.js

Here's the code that I could not get to work (it's a combination of http://www.aerotwist.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-three-js/ and http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/misc_controls_trackball.html and trying to make the object into a ring/torus):

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Getting Started with Three.js | Aerotwist</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The home of Creative Coder and developer Paul Lewis. Tutorial, experiments and considered opinions found here.">
  <meta name="author" content="Paul Lewis">


  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Three.js"></script>
    <script src="TrackballControls.js"></script>
    <script src="Detector.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
  #container {
    background: #000;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
  }
</style>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    controls.update();
  }
  function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
  }
  var WIDTH = 400,
      HEIGHT = 300;
  // set some camera attributes
  var VIEW_ANGLE = 45,
      ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT,
      NEAR = 0.1,
      FAR = 10000;
  // get the DOM element to attach to
  // - assume we've got jQuery to hand
  var $container = $('#container');
  // create a WebGL renderer, camera
  // and a scene
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  var camera =
    new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      VIEW_ANGLE,
      ASPECT,
      NEAR,
      FAR);
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // TrackBall code from http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/misc_controls_trackball.html
  var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
  controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
  controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
  controls.panSpeed = 0.8;
  controls.noZoom = false;
  controls.noPan = false;
  controls.staticMoving = true;
  controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;
  controls.keys = [ 65, 83, 68 ];
  //controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // this was how it used to be at: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/misc_controls_trackball.html
  controls.domElement.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // I changed this to fix error message: "controls.addEventListener is not a function"
  // --------------------------
  // add the camera to the scene
  scene.add(camera);
  // the camera starts at 0,0,0
  // so pull it back
  camera.position.z = 300;
  // start the renderer
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  // attach the render-supplied DOM element
  $container.append(renderer.domElement);
  // ------------------------
  // create the sphere's material
  var sphereMaterial =
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(
      {
        color: 0xCC0000
      });
  // -------------------------------
  // ################ try torus
  var centerpiece = new THREE.TorusGeometry();
  var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
    centerpiece,
    sphereMaterial);
  // add the sphere to the scene
  scene.add(sphere);
  // ---------------------------
  // create a point light
  var pointLight =
    new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
  // set its position
  pointLight.position.x = 10;
  pointLight.position.y = 50;
  pointLight.position.z = 130;
  // add to the scene
  scene.add(pointLight);
  // -------------------------
  // draw!
  renderer.render(scene, camera); 
</script>
```

Whenever I click anywhere on the page I get this error message:

```
_eye.copy(...).subSelf is not a function
```

Any ideas?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're using all the files from the same version. Ideally from the latest.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I tried your suggestion and updated the question with new information.  I'm still unable to get the trackball controls to work.  Any ideas where the latest builds of TrackballControls.js and Detector.js are located?  I've included the code in case your expert eyes can see some obvious noob mistake.  Thanks again for your time and making Three.js.  I'm excited to get this working and see the other capabilities of Three.js.  Take care!

Comment: Take the code from here: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/misc_controls_trackball.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  It's working now.  I was worried about the build in the example not supporting THREE.TorusGeometry, but it does so thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.